# in ruby Create a program that asks a user for 10 numbers and then returns the sum

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Im gonna ask you for 10 numbers and then give you the sum"
puts "Give me the first number"
first_number= gets.chomp
puts "Give me the second number"
second_number=gets.chomp
puts "Give me the third number "
third_number=gets.chomp
puts "Give me the fourth number"
fourth_number= gets.chomp
puts "Give me the fifth number"
fifth_number=gets.chomp
puts "Give me the sixth number"
sixth_number=gets.chomp
puts "Give me the seventh number"
seventh_number=gets.chomp
puts "Give me the eighth number"
eighth_number=gets.chomp
puts "Give me the ninth number"
ninth_number=gets.chomp
puts "Give me the tenth number"
tenth_number= gets.chomp
puts "The Sum of all your TEN numbers is:"
puts first_number.to_i + second_number.to_i+ third_number.to_i + fourth_number.to_i + fifth_number.to_i + sixth_number.to_i+ seventh_number.to_i+ eighth_number.to_i+ ninth_number.to_i + tenth_number.to_i
```

Comment: You can make use of the [ordinalize](https://rubygems.org/gems/ordinalize) gem. Then you can do `1.ordinalize #=> first`, `2.ordinalize #=> second` etc.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does the program have to be that verbose?

Answer (score 0):

```
 sum = 10.times.inject(0) do|sum,i| 
         puts "Enter #{i+1}th number"
         sum = sum + gets.chomp.to_f
       end
 puts "The sum is #{sum}"
```

This example works well with decimal and integer you pass.

> You are missing the point that, you are a software writer. You write softwares for end-users and its up to the users, how many numbers they want to enter. So I suggest you to learn writing dynamic softwares. **Do not just hard-code everything**. Make things flexible so that its easily tweak-able.

One idea is, you can even ask user how many numbers they want to enter.

Comment: `#{i+1}th` doesn't make sense for all `i` in `(1..10)`.

Comment: yes agreed, it does not in that case. One has to be careful.